# Formatting IP:Port string to

Tags: java, string, ip, port

I'm trying to make a little chat program for experimentation, but seeing as I'm not the best Java programmer, I don't know how to separate a port from an IP where they are both in the same string.

This isn't super clear, but here's basically what I want to do.
User enters IP and port in IP:Port format
Scanner grabs it and puts it into a String
Somehow put everything before the colon into a string and all numbers after the colon into an int.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: If you can assume that your input will be in the format IP:Port, you can use the `split()` method of the String class to split on the `:`. This will return you an array of two elements, first containing IP, second containing Port

Comment: I'll do some googling on that, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

First, you should check if the `String` contains a colon. Then, you can use [`String.split(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) and [`Integer.parseInt(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) with something like

```
String input = "127.0.0.1:8080"; // <-- an example input
int port = 80; // <-- a default port.
String host = null;
if (input.indexOf(':') > -1) { // <-- does it contain ":"?
  String[] arr = input.split(":");
  host = arr[0];
  try {
    port = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
} else {
  host = input;
}
System.out.printf("host = %s, port = %d%n", host, port);
```

Output is

```
host = 127.0.0.1, port = 8080
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String args[]){
        String allTogether= "ip:port";
        String[] array;

        if(allTogether.contains(":")){
            array = allTogether.split(":");
            String ip = array[0];
            String port = array[1];

            System.out.println(ip);
            System.out.println(port);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

to validate IP:PORT format you may try this:

```
public class Validator {

    private static final String IP_PORT_PATTERN =
            "^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
                    "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
                    "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
                    "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5]):" +
                    "([1-9][0-9]{0,3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])$";

    private static final Pattern PATTERN;

    static {
        PATTERN = Pattern.compile(IP_PORT_PATTERN);
    }

    public static boolean validate(final String s) {
        return PATTERN.matcher(s).matches();
    }

}
```

thanks to [frb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14882790/3767784) and [mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-ip-address-with-regular-expression/) :)

and to separate ip and port :

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String s = "127.0.0.1:8080";
    if (validate(s)) {
        String ip = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(':'));
        int port = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(s.indexOf(':') + 1));
        System.out.println(ip);
        System.out.println(port);
    } else {
        System.out.println("invalid format");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))
IP = splittedIP[0], Port = splittedIP[1] in String
you will need [Integer.parseInt](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_parseint.htm) to get the integer value of port

```
String[] ipSplit = "127.0.0.1:80".split(":");
String ip = ipSplit[0];
int port = Integer.parseInt(ipSplit[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "127.0.0.1:999";
String[] parts = s.split(":");
String address = parts[0];
int port = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
```

In this case, `address` will be `"127.0.0.1"` and `port` will be the `int` `999`.

Note that `Integer.parseInt` will throw a `NumberFormatException` in this case if the portion of the string after the `:` cannot be parsed as an integer, as in `"127.0.0.1:blahblah"`. As well, if the string does not contain a `:` there will be no `parts[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pattern matcher in java to get the address and the port information and by the way you can validate the input string as well.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX_FOR_IPADDRESS_WITH_PORT);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("127.0.0.1:80");
if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.printf("host = %s, port = %s%n", matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2));
} else {
    System.out.println("Invalid Ip Address");
}
```

You can have multiple regular expression to validate V4 and V6 addresses.
Hope this would help.